# Keep Wingdi graphics permanent

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I am making a C++ console application with lots of wingdi graphics mainly revolving around Rectangle() and FillRect() but as it is wingdi, the graphics are not permanent. The graphics get reset when i minimize the console, enlarge it, scroll down and whatsoever. I've seen in some threads that there is no predefined solution so you have to make one of your own.

One thing i tried, was drawing the rectangle once and then attaching a thread with infinite loop that checks the first pixel of rectangle in every iteration, if it's color is black, it draws whole rectangle again. As silly as it sounds, that's all i could think of. I know it's utterly inefficient. Is there any other solution for this?

Comment: Are you trying to draw on console window or something?

Comment: Console window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you've been able to use GDI to draw on your application's console window (presumably by calling `GetConsoleWindow` and then `GetDC`), it isn't really designed for that.  The system has code for the console window that tries to redraw the window itself whenever it needs to update.  It's not aware of anything your program does through GDI, so it has no way to preserve that.

If you just need to draw colorful rectangles on a console window, you can do those kinds of things with the [Console API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-reference).  You can set the text colors as needed and draw blocks of spaces or block characters.

If you want to do more general graphics, your program will have to create a (non-console) window, and then you can draw whatever you want whenever your window receives a WM_PAINT message.

Comment: Thanks Adrian that helped.